# Analytic extension for a a function defined in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I would like to know if it is possible to extend analytically any function of the type $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ to all complex plane. If it isn't possible, what should I assume to do so? If

Just an example: the function number of divisors of $n$.

EDIT: Is it unique?

Comment: Sorry, I want an holomorfic one or if it's not possible a meromorphic one.

Comment: @LeandroChiarini I'm fairly sure you can do this using the Weierstrass factorization theorem. To get the value at $1$, produce a function that is zero at all $n>1$, then scale to your desired value at $1$. Repeat this for each $n$, then add them all together. You will need to multiply each term by convergence factors to get the sum to converge, but it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.
First, put $$p_n(z)=\frac{(z-1)(z-2)\cdots(z-n+1)}{(n-1)!}$$ and note that $p_n(k)=0$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ while $p_n(n)=1$. Now let
$$ f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_ne^{a_n(z-n)}p_n(z),\qquad b_n=f(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_ke^{a_k(n-k)}p_k(n). $$
Just make sure that $a_n>0$ is big enough so that, say,
$$|f(n)e^{a_n(z-n)}p_n(z)|<2^{-n}$$ for all $z$ with $|z|\le n-1$.
Then the series converges uniformly on every bounded set.

Comment: Thanks Harald! So it's definitely not unique, right? Because we can take other values for $a_n$ as we want.

Comment: Oh, definitely not unique. You can also add any multiple of $\sin(\pi z)$.

Comment: By the way, I see a mistake. It is easily fixed. I have edited the answer. (I forgot that the $k$th summand is nonzero at $z=n$ for $n>k$.)